# LibreOffice: Convert PDF to Plain Text using --convert-to

Tags: pdf, libreoffice

I am trying to convert a pdf file to a plain text file using the following command

```
soffice --headless --convert-to txt xyz.pdf --outdir ~/
```

But the converted file does not contain the text but a bunch of unrecoginzed characters. Following is some of the text it creates

```
    PK^C^D^T^@^@^H^@^@Ås<89>A<85>l9<8a>.^@^@^@.^@^@^@^H^@^@^@mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheetPK^C^D^T^@^@^H^@^@Ås<89>A4éæSq^B^@^@q^B^@^@^H^@^@^@meta.xml<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<office:document-meta xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office" xmlns:grddl="http://www.w3.org/2003/g/data-view#" office:version="1.2"><office:meta><meta:document-statistic meta:table-count="1" meta:cell-count="2103" meta:object-count="0"/><meta:generator>LibreOffice/3.6$Linux_x86 LibreOffice_project/360m1$Build-102</meta:generator></office:meta></office:document-meta>PK^C^D^T^@^H^H^H^@Ås<89>A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^L^@^@^@settings.xmlµWÛRâ@^P}ß¯ æ]^C¨,¤^@^K±\ÝeÕ"è^Þ&IC¦<9c>L§æBd¿~'^D,^WC­Fç»...2<97>s:§»ÏLú§<8f>)o,A*<86>b@Z<87>MÒ^@^QaÌÄb@îf^W^G]r:üÔÇù<9c>EàÇ^X<99>^T<84>>P µ]¢^Zv»P~9= F
^_©bÊ^W4^EåëÈÇ^LÄv<9b>ÿ|µ¿&+G^^9^S^O^C<92>h<9d>ù<9e><97>çùa~t<88>ráµz½<9e>·<9e>Ý.<8d>PÌÙâµTåêçT<88>øDTl(<83>Y<93>µ<9b>Íc¯|&<8d>M<90>Ï¤i<93>áV<87>íë^Oû^[<82>òç<80>iH^Km^Z<9b>á"´^A±<94>þ<92>Aþ¤^Z©Ú÷ï<9e>{¦XÈa$<81>Î0#ÛI½Êì$^S<9a>^L<9b>}ï%È<9b><80>'0×n<90>^?°X'UÐíæq·Û{7þ%°ER^Y{·Ó9i<9d>T^ST^L^V)y}^RË^A#©¶%ñ<96>lN<90>ÆS 1
```

It is the same case if I try to convert a PDF file to HTML or DOC

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Approach using a different tool: `pdftotext xyz.pdf` (For Ubuntu: `sudo apt install poppler-utils`)

Answer (score -1):

Try to put the "Text" after "txt".
For example:

```
libreoffice --invisible --convert-to txt:Text filename.doc
```

Suppose "libreoffice" and "soffice" are the same enough

Comment: I believe this person was asking whether libreoffice (or soffice?) can convert .pdf file (not .doc file) --> to --> text. This is the same question that led me to this post. The information in the top right corner of this web page indicates that the question was asked one year ago.